# My shower tile goes past the drywall on an outside corner

Tags: tile

[image]

The bullnose tile along the corner is just about flush with the drywall towards the floor but goes about a 1/2 inch past the drywall going up toward the ceiling.  I'm looking for the best way to fix this.

Comment: Which one is actually vertical? In general, and when possible, you're going to want to make any out-of-plumb surfaces or lines exactly vertical.

Comment: what are we looking at on the right half of the picture?  an unfinished wall surface?  or are we looking at the end of a partition wall and an opening?

Comment: @DaveTweed  I would say if the tiles are not plumb, then it's best (visually) to match the tile unless you've got a door jamb or something else plumb very near this finished corner.

Comment: Do you have room to fur out the wall a couple of inches?

Comment: This corner will transition from tile to drywall with paint.  The tile is about a 1/2 inch past the drywall.  On the right there will eventually be recessed shelving.  Not sure what you mean by which one is vertical.

Comment: By fur you mean remove the drywall that is there and install new drywall with tar paper or something on the stud to make the drywall meet the tile?

Answer (score 1):

Say hello to joint compound (aka mud); it covers a multitude of sins. Mud it up until it's even with the tile. Start with hot (dry powder, mix with water, sets) mud.

Comment: ok thanks for that advice.  I considered using mud but thought that 1/2 an inch was too much of a gap to use mud.

Comment: Takes a few layers, and you could infill with 1/4 and 3/8 drywall if you really wanted to, but given that the error tapers that will only reduce the gap a bit. If you do the bulk of it in hot mud (which shrinks less since it sets rather than drying) it should be fine. Do give adequate cure/dry time between coats.

Comment: Ok I will make sure that I use hot mud and will do it in layers.  Thanks Ecnerwal.  I will also make sure each coat has time to dry. Any other tips? This will be my first time dealing with drywall mud, should I use tape with the layers.